# How to set a border for Word 2016 text and hold its fill color

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editing, microsoft-word-2016, outline

I'm trying to set a border/outline to some text, but I don't get what I really want.

I'd like to outline the whole text while preserving its *white* color.

This is the sample text and current text effect's settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: is that what you are trying to get?]

I don't quite get what you are trying to do but is that the result you want?